# How to test an angularJS service with httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, testing

I am quite new to angularJS. Trying to test an angular service with httpBackend but can't get it working. What am I doing wrong? Tried other answers on SO having similar issues, but the closest I got to was the following (still not working, the xData is undefined):

**xApp.services.js**

```
'use strict';
var services = angular.module('xApp.services', []);
services.factory('xService', function ($http, $location) {
    var urlPath = $location.path() || 'http://localhost:8000';
    var xData;

    var getXData = function () {
        var promise = $http.get(urlPath + '/xData')
            .then(function (res) {
                xData = res.data;
                return xData;
            });
        return promise;
    };
    return {
       getXData:  getXData
    };
});
```

**xServiceSpec.js**

```
describe('xService', function () {
    beforeEach(module('xApp.services'));
    var $httpBackend;
    var xData;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/xData').respond(
            {
                _id: 25,
                name: "TestName",
                xarr: [
                    {
                        _id: 11,
                        name: "TestArrName",
                        created: "2013-09-29"
                    }
                ]
            }
        );
        $httpBackend.when('POST', '/newXArr').respond("ok");
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (xService) {
        xService.getXData().then(function (data) {
            xData = data;
        });
    }));

    describe('definition', function () {
        it('should be called', inject(function (xService) {
            xService.getXData().then(function (data) {
                xData = data;
            });
            expect(xData).toBeDefined();
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: can you try adding `$httpBackend.flush();` after the `.when(..).respond(..)` part? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend

Comment: "Error: No pending request to flush !"

Comment: maybe you cna make a plnkr? there is a feature to have jasmine

Comment: @EduardGamonal Try to call `$httpBackend.flush()` after `xService.getXData()`

Comment: @YeLiu  your suggestion works. Create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @x-man You have it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @EduardGamonal mentioned in his comment, you need to call `$httpBackend.flush()`, but you should call it *after* you made a http request, that is after `xService.getXData()`; otherwise, there will be no outstanding http request to handle, so $httpBackend will give you the "No pending request to flush" error.